# What permission I need from instagram to show the followers list in my IOS App

Tags: instagram-api

I want to show the followers or following list of the user who logged into the instagram through my app. Should I need any permission from the instagram.

Answer (score 0):

You will need `basic` and `follower_list` permissions (and also `public_content` maybe). Try in sandbox mode by added one of your follower to sandbox user.

(Whether you get approved or not by Instagram is whole different game, depends if your app meets Instagram approved usecase)

Comment: thanks for the answers....can you please tell me the reason why InsTrack app now don't have the permission to show the followers and following list in their app while other app with same functionality working fine

Comment: ask InsTrack, may be they dont have permission